# How to make google form redirect to custom URL

Tags: html, google-forms

I want to make my google form which I embedded in my html, redirect to my thank you page after submission.

All I have is this in a blank html page:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcseG01hClEZ_FCMq5QzfrzY5JWtCLdLm7LwmXsDfMKuqL1g/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Just replace http://example.com/ with the address you want it to redirect to (after the function)
Do this after the function so they complete the form and it redirects them to another page.

I believe this is what you are asking however, if not let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much!