# Redirect a google form to another html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have embedded a google form to HTML form like this. The form is subitted and redirected to google page insted I want to redirect to [Here](https://vitalhulladek.hu/thankyou.html). How can I do so?:

```
<form name="contact" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLScG84LTIBt7p8dKjkg3uWCT2rgPDs1VGGNY1D58yEW5REiOFA/formResponse" id="popupForm" target="_self" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="entry.79543200" placeholder="Cégnév/Név" class="w_100">
                    <input type="text" name="entry.94732913" placeholder="Telefonszám" class="w_100">
                    <div class="cleaner"></div>
                    <label id="" class="error" for="approxAmount"></label>
                    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="checkContainer">
                            <span class="chkForm">
                                <label class="custom-form">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entry.1724649034" value="0-100 kg">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="chkText">100 kg alatti hulladék</span>
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkContainer">
                            <span class="chkForm">
                                <label class="custom-form">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entry.1724649034" value="100-500 kg">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="chkText">100-500 kg</span>
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkContainer">
                            <span class="chkForm">
                                <label class="custom-form">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entry.1724649034" value="500+ kg">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="chkText">500+ kg</span>
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <div class="cleaner"></div>
                    <label id="" class="error" for="agree"></label>
                    <div class="cleaner"></div>
                    <div class="checkContainer">
                        <span class="chkForm">
                            <label class="custom-form">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="entry.959539170" value="agree" class="agree" id="agree" required>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="chkText">Elfogadom az <a href="/files/adatvedelem.pdf" target="_blank" title="adatvédelmi nyilatkozat">adatvédelmi nyilatkozatot</a>.
                        </span>
                    </div>t
                    <div class="cleaner"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="send3" id="submit-popup" value="Regisztráció" class="w_100 btn cta normal">
                </form>
```

[image]

Right now the form redirect to the submit page of google form like in picture how can I redirect it to thankyou.html after submitting data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make google form redirect to custom URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524769/how-to-make-google-form-redirect-to-custom-url)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-popup').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = "https://vitalhulladek.hu/thankyou.html";
    });
  });
</script>

<form name="contact" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLScG84LTIBt7p8dKjkg3uWCT2rgPDs1VGGNY1D58yEW5REiOFA/formResponse" id="popupForm" target="_self" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="entry.79543200" placeholder="Cégnév/Név" class="w_100">
  <input type="text" name="entry.94732913" placeholder="Telefonszám" class="w_100">
  <div class="cleaner"></div>
  <label id="" class="error" for="approxAmount"></label>
  <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="checkContainer">
      <span class="chkForm">
                                <label class="custom-form">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entry.1724649034" value="0-100 kg">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="chkText">100 kg alatti hulladék</span>
      </label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkContainer">
      <span class="chkForm">
                                <label class="custom-form">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entry.1724649034" value="100-500 kg">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="chkText">100-500 kg</span>
      </label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkContainer">
      <span class="chkForm">
                                <label class="custom-form">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entry.1724649034" value="500+ kg">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="chkText">500+ kg</span>
      </label>
      </span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="cleaner"></div>
  <label id="" class="error" for="agree"></label>
  <div class="cleaner"></div>
  <div class="checkContainer">
    <span class="chkForm">
                            <label class="custom-form">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="entry.959539170" value="agree" class="agree" id="agree" required>
                                <span class="check"></span>
    </label>
    </span>
    <span class="chkText">Elfogadom az <a href="/files/adatvedelem.pdf" target="_blank" title="adatvédelmi nyilatkozat">adatvédelmi nyilatkozatot</a>.
                        </span>
  </div>t
  <div class="cleaner"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="send3" id="submit-popup" value="Regisztráció" class="w_100 btn cta normal">
</form>
```

Basically you would use javascript (jquery) to detect when the submit button is clicked, you'll be rerouted to the 'thank you' page. Is this what you mean't?

Comment: well it gets redirected to new window but the data is not submitted

Comment: What backend language are you using with your javascript? PHP? Ruby? Python?

Comment: No Backend. Only client site js and i am using google form and data will go its Google sheet

Comment: Never had experience with that before, check if this link helps https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0r8t77E5qzEk/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2Fr8t77E5qzEk

Best of luck